# ActiveX thread HIGH CPU usage

Tags: vb6, activex

I wrote an ActiveX exe that reads data from a socket and updates the database.
When i create several threads (i am testing with 5 at present) from client,Activex exe is taking 100% CPU usage.Sometimes All threads starts but none will finish.I am using events in ActiveX exe.

The ActiveX exe has only two tasks

```
 a.Read from socket
 b.update database.
```

The size of ActiveX exe is about 55KB.

Where did i go wrong?

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you debugged and/or profiled the .exe to find out where it's spending it's time?  I'd bank on there being a tight loop somewhere in your code that constantly checks whether data is available on the socket - which would lead to high CPU usage.

Comment: @Will,is there any profiling tool available for VB6?

Comment: I've barely touched VB6 to be honest, so I'm not sure - would expect that there will be such tools, tho'.  If you run up your app in the debugger and break into it from time to time you should get a good feel for where the majority of the CPU time is going.

Comment: There is a profiling tool available here... http://www.aivosto.com/vbwatch.html , and it does most of what one could wish for. You do have to pay for it, though.

Answer (score 0):

If the two lines of code you posted above fall inside a loop (for / Do While / Loop While) then make sure to include

```
DoEvents
```

to allow the program to handle events (like mouse clicks, keyboard, form re-size and minimize, etc.) while it is busy processing the rest of the code.

```
a.Read from socket
DoEvents
b.update database
```